# TideSDK popup "save to dialog" onclick <a href="">

Tags: tidesdk

Using the TideSDK, I am creating a desktop app for users able to view and save the file.

In my index.html I have over 50 zipped files which I would like it to prompt user "save to disk" when clicking on the link (as below). How do I solve this? Many thanks!

Example:

```
<a href="filename1.zip">save to desktop...
<a href="filename2.zip">save to desktop..
```

Answer (score 1):

You could capture the click, use Ti.UI.currentWindow.openFolderChooserDialog to allow the user to choose a location to download the file too, and then use the Ti.Filesystem api to copy the file to the destination.